# Is Iframe based payment gateway integration with civicrm possible?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor

Is it possible to integrate a payment gateway which gives an iframe to collect user details.I tried it almost 2 years back and failed for some reason I dont remember now. If it's possible and someone has a sample code please do share, it would be a great help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply samuelsov. Even I tried a year back without any success. Is there anyone who has implemented iFrame based payment gateway with CiviCRM?

Comment: something else to consider is the security issue related to this approach

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's easy. I have tried without success a couple years ago. 
The return page will go to the iframe rather than the parent page and i didn't find a way to close the iframe and having the Thank you page on the parent page.

I know that there is a lot of work that is being done lately regarding payment refactoring but i don't know if it tackle this kind of problem.